# How to check the log when Trigger is turned On and Off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I want to check when my trigger is turned on and off in SQL Server 2005 database. I have created a trigger which inserts entry into new table whenever there is change in specific column. But I received a complaint from client saying that log is not maintained for all updated records in Log Table.

I feel it may be due to trigger is turned off while updating some records so it may not have been recorded in log table.

So how to see log record of whether trigger is turned on or off?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear what you're looking for.

Do you want to be able to check at any given time whether the trigger is on or off? In that case, use this statement:

```
SELECT is_disabled
FROM sys.triggers
WHERE name = 'your-trigger-name-here'
```

If you want to track when a given trigger is disabled, you could write a [DDL trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that catches the `ALTER_TRIGGER` event and makes a note of who and when a given trigger was disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your query returns current status of trigger. I want to see the complete log when trigger is turned On or Off along with date time. e.g. I created trigger on Sep 5 and it is turned off on sep 7 and turned back on sep 8, sql server should show me the complete log record of these trigger status change.

Comment: @Rahul: that's what I mentioned in the second part of my response - in that case, you will need to set up **DDL triggers** to capture that information and then use it

Comment: Thanks, I will write trigger for that for future entries, but is there any way to track previous changes in Trigger status?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge. If you're interested in this, you have to record it yourself, using DDL triggers. There's no built-in "log" of these events

Answer (score 0):

I put this answer for whom may search for this question.
You can use this statement to see more detail and the last modify date and time of trigger.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM sys.triggers
 WHERE name = 'your-trigger-name-here'
```